# How to transfer files from one remote location to another using java?

Tags: java, ftp, file-transfer, remote-server, webdav

I want to write java program to download files directly to remote server rather than downloading on local machine.

Remote server is FTP/WebDAV

So is there any library in java to download files directly to remote ftp/WebDAV server rather than saving it to local machine and uploading it.

Please lead in proper direction

Comment: This is too broad. There are several ways to do that. Choosing one depends on several circumstances of your environment. Please explain your environment in detail and - important - show us your attempts, and where you failed.

Comment: Agreeing with @Seelenvirtuose. This way to broad and is lacking severely in details. Please describe the problem you're facing in greater detail and then attempt to seek help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is too broad, but I would recommend you the following steps:

1) Download the file into your system using the [Java NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html)

2) Get the file you downloaded and send it to the web server you have access using the [Ftp Client](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-1.4.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) like following:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
try {
client.connect("ftp.domain.com");
client.login("username", "pass");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("path_of_the_downloaded_file");
client.storeFile(filename, fileInputStream );
client.logout();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
try {
    if (fileInputStream != null) {
        fileInputStream .close();
    }
    client.disconnect();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

============================= EDIT =================================

Reply to comment: "but I don't want to store file locally, not even temporarily"

Then you just need to store it in a byte array, and convert the byte array to an InputStream and send store the file to your server

```
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("www.example.com/file.pdf").openStream());
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    client.connect("ftp.domain.com");
    client.login("username", "pass");
    client.storeFile("fileName", stream);
    stream.close();
```

Comment: but I don't want to store file locally, not even temporarily

Comment: @sr196 as you can see, I edited my answer to fit your case